# How do you achieve in Selenium what you achieve with BeautifulSoup's prettify()?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

You can run `.prettify()` method on `BeautifulSoup` object to get a full, formated version of your fetched `HTML`.

I realized that `Selenium` doesn't have this particular method or anything similarly worded method.

How do you print a prittified version of your `HTML` for debugging purposes in `Selenium`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `browser.page_source`.

For example:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://en.wikipedia.org")
html = browser.page_source
time.sleep(2)
print(html)

browser.close()
```

But... to *beautify it* you'd still need e.g. `BeautifulSoup` as `selenium` doesn't have such a function.